# Why can't I loop through this SimpleXML Object?

Tags: php, foreach, simplexml

I've been pulling my hair out over this, I really hope I can get some help. Thanks in advance!

I have a SimpleXML object, which goes something like this:

```
Object
(
|    SomeStuff Object
|    (
|    )
|    Entries Object
|    (
|    |    Entry Object
|    |    (
|    |    |    SomeMoreStuff Object
|    |    |    (
|    |    |    )
|    |    |    ImportantStuff Object
|    |    |    (
|    |    |    |    W1 Object
|    |    |    |    (
|    |    |    |    |    D1 Object
|    |    |    |    |    (
|    |    |    |    |    )
|    |    |    |    |    D2 Object
|    |    |    |    W2 Object
|    |    |    |    (
|    |    |    |    |    D1 Object
|    |    |    |    |    (
|    |    |    |    |    )
|    |    |    |    |    D2 Object
```

..., etc.
For some reason, using the following code produces unexpected results:

```
foreach($xml->Entries->Entry->ImportantStuff as $key => $value) {
   echo "$key, $value";
}
```

Just outputs `ImportantStuff,` instead of a line for each `D#`. In another situation, I have an object where each member of ImportantStuff has the same name, and in this case I use `$xml->ImportantStuff->ImportantThing`, which returns *all* ImportantThings. How can I emulate this where the important things have different names?

Comment: Can you add your full xml ???

Comment: @Baba, I realise that you cannot `echo` the object, but it was for testing purposes to ensure that the iteration was actually working. :)

Comment: @Baba, I would, but it's been answered! Thanks, Geek Num 88

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using simplexml you need to do the foreach like this

`foreach($xml->Entries->Entry->ImportantStuff->children() as $key => $value) {
   echo "$key, $value";
}`